# Chinese font-family not displaying in browsers

Tags: css, utf-8, fonts, chinese-locale

I've got a website which has had it's content translated into Mandarin. I'm attempting to paste it in but can't get it to display in the browser.

The translated content was given to me in Excel using the font SimSun, which I have on my computer. I usually use UltraEdit but it wouldn't display SimSun so I'm using Wordpad for now instead since it displays SimSun just fine.

Relevant parts of the html:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="cmn">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mandarin.css" />

<li><a href="about.html" id="sm0">关于我们</a></li>
```

And all of mandarin.css:

```
body, p, li, a, 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, 宋体, SimSun, 华文细黑, STXihei, sans-serif;
}
```

Firebug shows mandarin.css in the usual style list for my link element, and lists the selectors, but not the rule e.g.

```
body, p, li, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
}
```

But the previous rule is overridden: 
body {
        color: #222222;
        cursor: auto;
        <strike>font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;</strike>
    }

And the content is switched to question marks, which is how it displays in all browsers:

```
<li><a id="sm0" href="about.html">????</a></li>
```

What else do I need to do to get this to display properly?

***Edited to add:*** a code-pen setup with just the relevant parts, plus frameworks, all my CSS and scripts which might affect it. SimSun displays well, so I'm now wondering if WordPad is not correctly saving my markup after all?

```html
<p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="JoOmBJ" data-default-tab="result" data-user="stringyland" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/stringyland/pen/JoOmBJ/'>HTML List Demos</a> by Julie Grundy (<a href='http://codepen.io/stringyland'>@stringyland</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you Try making it work with a different CSS rule? ** font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", "Microsoft YaHei", 微软雅黑, STXihei, 华文细黑, serif;**

Comment: Which libraries/frameworks are you using? Have you checked that the code posted actually reproduces the issue?

Comment: Good questions! I'll make a jsfiddle and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think UltraEdit will display Chinese text just fine, you need to make sure to use correct encoding for both source (in UltraEdit, and where you copy the text from into UE). Firstly, set UE to UTF-8, Secondly, try to save that Excel to plain .txt or .csv and drag the saved file to Firefox, see if it displays correctly. If not, go to View > Encoding > Chinese GBK. Then you can copy the text from there to UltraEdit.

Comment: You're correct! I'd made some changes in the config, but apparently there are quite a lot of bits to pay attention to to get UltraEdit to display these fonts. I followed all the steps here: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/unicode.html and now it's working perfectly, and displaying as intended in the browser. Thanks for the heads up.